# Submission of form in two stages

Tags: cognito-forms

I don't think this feature is part of the Cognito Forms system, but inquiring here to see if I'm missing something. We need to be able to have a two-part form, where users will submit the first part of the form, then our form admins will review the form and (I suppose this is how it could work) then check an admin-only internal field as "Approved" -- which would then trigger a confirmation email to the user with a link to fill out the second part of the form (which would ideally be on a second, separate form page). This second part of the form would have field(s) for collecting payments.

The important part here is to have each of the two parts of the form posting data to the same form database. Our latest implementation had two forms, with two separate databases, which made administering the data a pain.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: This is definitely possible in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) - check out our blog post that walks you through creating a form with two stage submissions: http://blog.cognitoforms.com/enhancing-your-workflow-with-two-stage-submissions

Comment: Thanks for that info... 

So, could I use a page break to place that second part of the form on a second page, and would there be a way to either have a unique link to only that second part, or have the second part only display dynamically based on the conditional logic attached to the Approved selector?

Would be best if the user didn't have to be looking at that first part of the form that they already submitted.

Comment: There are a couple different ways you could accomplish this. I would recommend putting the first part of your form into one section and the second part into another. You could then set the first section to only appear when the Approved field is marked No (make sure that No is already selected as the default option) and set the second section to only appear when the Approved field is marked Yes.

Answer (score -1):

This is definitely possible in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) - check out our blog post that walks you through creating a form with two stage submissions:

http://blog.cognitoforms.com/enhancing-your-workflow-with-two-stage-submissions

Here's essentially how it works:

1. First, enable Entry Link Sharing under your Form Settings. Then, configure the email template - this is the notification containing the entry link that your users will receive after their submission is approved. Note: If your form is embedded, make sure to include the URL of where the form is located on your website. This will ensure that users are taken back to your embedded form on your webpage when they edit their entries.
2. Add a Yes/No field to your form called First Stage Approved, set to only display Internally.
3. Add a section or additional fields that you want to appear after the first stage is approved. Then, select Show This Field - When for the section/fields and make them appear when the First Stage Approved field is Yes.
4. Following first stage submission, review the form from the Entries page, and set First Stage Approved to Yes if approved. Doing so will trigger the additional section/fields to appear on the entry.
5. Select the Share option from the top of the individual entry, and set Link Expires to When Submitted to change the status back to Incomplete.
6. Send the email notification with the approval message. This email should be filled in and ready to go if you already configured your email template in the builder.
7. Your users will receive an email notifying them that their submission was approved, along with a link to edit their entry, which now contains additional fields:

Comment: Thanks for that info... 

So, could I use a page break to place that second part of the form on a second page, and would there be a way to either have a unique link to only that second part, or have the second part only display dynamically based on the conditional logic attached to the Approved selector?

Would be best if the user didn't have to be looking at that first part of the form that they already submitted.

Comment: There are a couple different ways you could accomplish this. I would recommend putting the first part of your form into one section and the second part into another. You could then set the first section to only appear when the Approved field is marked No (make sure that No is already selected as the default option) and set the second section to only appear when the Approved field is marked Yes.